# Is it a good practice in C++ to add members into abstract class that is an interface?

Tags: c++, interface, abstract, pure-virtual

I need to write an abstract class that defines an interface.
All its methods are pure virtual ones.
Now, there are a few members that should be in that class as well, and my question -
is it a good c++ practice to add them in this class or should I define a new class (let's call it: class members) that contains those members, and the derived class will inherit from both: the interface class and the member class.
thanks

Comment: I would avoid multiple inheritance where possible.  It has a runtime overhead if nothing else.

Comment: [CppCoreGuidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) have a bit of guidance. They suggest to have pure abstract interface classes without data.

Comment: I'd write an interface class without members, then an abstract base class with the common members that inherits from the interface class, then a concrete class that inherits from the abstract base class.  Assuming you can't avoid it altogether (as per Paul's comment).

Comment: Just add on, NVI, non-virtual interface, is also an excellent practice.

Comment: @PaulSanders Only if there are virtual bases

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings -- there is a **minor** performance hit when accessing some of the non-virtual bases, since the `this` pointer has to be adjusted to point at the appropriate base subobject. That's just an addition to or subtraction from the address in `this`. It's not something I'd spend more than a millisecond worrying about.

Comment: @PeteBecker It can be done statically unless there are virtual bases, no?

Comment: The appropriate offset is known at compile-time.

Comment: IMHO, this is one of those "opinion" answers.  I have worked with interfaces only classes and classes that are interfaces and contain common data members.  If you want to go through the "pure" route, the abstract interface will have no members.  Another class would inherit from the abstract interface and add members and possibly default implementations.  I just think it's a lot of extra coding to go through the "pure" route.  I'd rather add default methods and add some members to the interface and refactor at a later date as necessary.